# BigQuery Streaming Insert Error - Repeated record added outside of an array

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm facing a weird problem while using Dataflow Streaming Insert.
I have a JSON with a lot of records and arrays. I set up the Pipeline with Streaming Insert method and a class DeadLetters to handle the errors.

```java
formattedWaiting.apply("Insert Bigquery ",
                BigQueryIO.<KV<TableRow,String>>write()
                .to(customOptions.getOutputTable())
                .withFormatFunction(kv -> kv.getKey())
                .withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STREAMING_INSERTS)
                .withSchemaFromView(schema)
                .withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
                .withWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
                .withFailedInsertRetryPolicy(InsertRetryPolicy.retryTransientErrors())
                .withoutValidation()
                .withExtendedErrorInfo()
                .withTimePartitioning(new TimePartitioning().setField(customOptions.getPartitionField().get()))
                .withClustering(clusteringFieldsList)
                .withExtendedErrorInfo())
                .getFailedInsertsWithErr()
                .apply("Taking 1 element insertion", Sample.<BigQueryInsertError>any(1))
                .apply("Insertion errors",ParDo.of(new DeadLettersHandler()));
```

The problem is when I'm using the streaming insert method, some rows don't insert into the table and I'm receiving the error:

*Repeated record with name: XXXX added outside of an array.*

I double-checked the JSON that has the problem and everything seems fine.
The weird part is when I comment the *withMethod* line, the row insert with no issue at all.

I don't know why the pipeline has that behavior.

The JSON looks like this.

```json
{
   "parameters":{
      "parameter":[
         {
            "subParameter":[
               {
                  "value":"T",
                  "key":"C"
               },
               {
                  "value":"1",
                  "key":"SEQUENCE_NUMBER"
               },
               {
                  "value":"1",
                  "key":"SEQUENCE_NUMBER"
               }
            ],
            "value":"C",
            "key":"C"
         },
         {
            "subParameter":[
               {
                  "value":"T",
                  "key":"C"
               },
               {
                  "value":"1",
                  "key":"SEQUENCE_NUMBER"
               },
               {
                  "value":"2",
                  "key":"SEQUENCE_NUMBER"
               }
            ],
            "value":"C",
            "key":"C"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

The BigQuery schema is fine because I can insert data while commenting the streaming insert line in the BigQueryIO

Any idea fellows?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't suppose you ever got to the bottom of this did you?we're hitting the same issue

Comment: @jamiet I added the answer and how we fixed the problem. Maybe it can help, let me know!

Comment: That’s helpful, much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just an update to this question.

The problem was with the schema declaration and the JSON itself.

We defined the `parameters` column as `RECORD REPEATED` but `parameters` is an object in the JSON example.

So we have two options here.

1. Change the BigQuery schema from `RECORD REPEATED` to `RECORD NULLABLE`
2. Add a bracket [] to the `parameters` object, for this option you will have to transform the JSON and add the brackets to treat the object as an array.

Example:

```
{
   "parameters":[
      {
         "parameter":[
            {
               "subParameter":[
                  {
                     "value":"T",
                     "key":"C"
                  },
                  {
                     "value":"1",
                     "key":"SEQUENCE_NUMBER"
                  },
                  {
                     "value":"1",
                     "key":"SEQUENCE_NUMBER"
                  }
               ],
               "value":"C",
               "key":"C"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```